# Show all images in a directory on an html page automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a directory on my server called "Uploads". It is full of images that users have uploaded. Each time somebody uploads an image, it adds it to the directory. I am using the css property `display: grid;` for my images to be in a nice grid. Here is the basic layout :

```css
.imgSet {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        
        .imgSet div {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            background-color: #333;
            border: 2px solid lightgrey;
        }
        
        .downloadImg {
            width: 95%;
            display: block;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
```

```html
<div class="imgSet">
                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <br>

                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <a href="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg" download><img class="downloadImg" class="downloadImg" src="https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg"><h3>Click an image to download it.</h3></a>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
```

I want each image in the Uploads directory to create a new div, a, and image tag for it to be in. The src attribute, as well as the href attribute of the a tag need to contain the url /Uploads/imageurl.extension as well as holding the same classes. If there is an easy way to do this with javascript it would help my page a lot. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added the divs directly through javascript. I looped through the array of links to create the divs. I didn't really do much with css. There are 3 pictures in each row. If you want something else just change the css and the array in javascript to edit the image links.

```js
const links = ['https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg', 'https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg', 'https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg', 'https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg', 'https://jeffthecow.com/assets/images/jeffinSpace.jpg'];

for (link of links) {
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML += `<div>
  <a href=${link}>
  <img src=${link} alt="jeffthecow" width=120 />
  </a>
  </div>`;
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Okay, this is great for me to generate the containers and images, but is there a way to automatically feed in all of the const links? I would prefer for that system to be automated.

Comment: @ilsloaoycd What do you mean? The images in my example already acts as links when you click on it. Do you have image files? For an example, if you have the files in the same working directory, you can do "./image.jpg" for the image url.

Comment: I mean in the javascript `const links = []`. I have to type in all my image URLs. I was wondering if javascript could automatically write those links for me for any image added to my directory.

Comment: @ilsloaoycd I don't know if my answer is efficient but here: Have your images be accessible with a link, like typing mywebsite.com/images/image1.jpg shows image1.jpg. Also have mywebsite.com/imagelink or whatever name you want return an array of all the image file names. From the client side, make a fetch request for mywebsite.com/imagelink to get the array. So, instead of creating the array on the client side, get it from your server.

Comment: I will try it. :)